# SQL > Server > How to query for additional fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have the following query and it works perfectly and gives me 200 rows. However, I wanted to retrieve additional fields from ExecutionLogStorage table. When I added ExecutionLogStorage.TimeStart, ExecutionLogStorage.TimeDataRetrieval with group by the result is 8,000+ rows. How can I retrieve the latest date (Max of the date) and still keep 200 rows of data.

```
Select * from (
SELECT        ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, COUNT(*) AS HitCount, Catalog.Name, ExecutionLogStorage.UserName
FROM            [SP_RPT_SVC].[dbo].ExecutionLogStorage INNER JOIN
                         Catalog ON [SP_RPT_SVC].[dbo].ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID = Catalog.ItemID
where Catalog.[Type] = 2
GROUP BY ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, Catalog.Name, ExecutionLogStorage.UserName) X

LEFT Join

(SELECT [Id]     
      ,[DirName]
      ,[LeafName] 
FROM [SP_BI].[dbo].[AllDocs]) Y
on
Y.ID = X.ReportID

LEFT Join

(SELECT [NTName],[PreferredName]
  FROM [SP_ProfileDB].[dbo].[UserProfile_Full]) Z
ON
X.UserName = Z.NTName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I retrieve the latest date (Max of the date) and still keep 200 rows of data.

No need to modify the `GROUP BY` clause: just add more aggregate functions to your inner query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT        
        ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, 
        COUNT(*) AS HitCount, 
        Catalog.Name, 
        ExecutionLogStorage.UserName,
        MAX(ExecutionLogStorage.TimeStart) MaxTimeStart --> here,
        MAX(ExecutionLogStorage.TimeDataRetrieval) MaxTimeDataRetrieval --> and here
    FROM [SP_RPT_SVC].[dbo].ExecutionLogStorage 
    INNER JOIN Catalog 
        ON [SP_RPT_SVC].[dbo].ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID = Catalog.ItemID
    WHERE Catalog.[Type] = 2
    GROUP BY 
        ExecutionLogStorage.ReportID, 
        Catalog.Name, 
        ExecutionLogStorage.UserName
) X
LEFT JOIN ...
```

Comment: worked perfectly in first try. thank you so much for the quick reply. i appreciate it.